# WebApp. Java EE. Where I should initialize my business logic?

Tags: java, servlets

I recently started learning  java EE (jsp, servlets and some patterns for working with database like a DAO) and I dont understand where I should initialize my bussines logic? I think that create instances of it in body of do*** servlet methods is a bad practice. P.S. my app use DataSource and ConnectionPool for connection with db.

Comment: what's the use case and what you have currently?

Comment: See my answer, I would say search for Servlet load on startup, ServletContextListener and EJB startup and singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your requirement somehow, what initialization you are looking for. Is it a EJB solution? Pure Servlet/JSP solution? etc.

Normally when deploying your application, after an invocation the application will load the required logic.

Of course you can do initialize to speed up the load, to make required code run before users enter the application etc.

In EJB we are talking about @Singleton and @Startup annotations.

For servlet you can use the annotation @WebServlet(name="startup", loadOnStartup="0"). Or put it in your web.xml. Depends how you code.

A more recommended way is to create you own listener, and override the contextInitialized and contextDestoryed methods. E.g. create db connection etc in initialized method and deregister the driver in contextdestory method. Use annotation @WebServletContextListener or add the listener to your web.xml

Also Java web server specific solutions exists, you need to check your vendor.